# Image thumbnail from pdf not displaying in IE8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internet-explorer-8, amazon-s3, pdf-generation, paperclip

I have a very strange problem with an thumbnail image, which generates from an uploaded PDF via paperclip in a rails app. The uploaded files are stored on Amazon S3. Paperclip generates a thumbnail image of the first page of the uploaded pdf. This works fine and the thumb image can be viewed in all browsers, except IE8. Here you only see an X

Here is the url of one sample generated thumbnail (https://s3.amazonaws.com/production.harold-scholz.de/pictures/70/Sonderdruck BWI 11-04-original-thumb.jpg).

Does anyone have a clue?

Comment: If the problem still exists, can you re-post the image? The URL doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something to do with the spaces in the web address? Have you tried removing them and seeing if this resolves the issue?